# how to enable text compression in laravel/vue project?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

[image]

lighthouse shows following solution.

I tried this in my .htaccess file. but in net work content-encoding is not displayed. i thied sing g.zip compression

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# for text compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

</IfModule>
```

I tried this in my .htaccess file. but in net work content-encoding is not displayed. i thied sing g.zip compression
[image]

Comment: Encryption or compression?

Comment: have you tried running `npm run production` for production environment in stead of `npm run watch`?

Answer (score 4):

For `@vue/cli` projects:

- `yarn add -D compression-webpack-plugin` (or `npm`/`pnpm` equivalent)
- in `vue.config.js` (create it in root if you don't have it):

```js
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin")
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new CompressionPlugin(),
      /* other plugins */
    ]
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could use the existing [vue-cli plugin](https://github.com/AnWeber/vue-cli-plugin-compression). Read installation and configuration docs.

---

For `vite` projects:

- `yarn add -D vite-plugin-compression` (or `npm`/`pnpm` equivalent)
- in `vite.config.js` (create it in root if you don't have it):

```js
import viteCompression from 'vite-plugin-compression'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    viteCompression(),
    /* other plugins */
  ],
})
```